# Dividing a large file into several smaller, stochastic writing to multiple files

Tags: python, io

It's a bit embarrassing but I having a bit of a difficulty with a rather simple (at least it should be) task:

I want to have a script that takes a large text file (several GBs) and divides into smaller pieces. This partitioning however is supposed to happen not on the order of lines but based on matching string patterns, such that each line/entry is supposed to be categorized based on the starting characters. So the algorithm looks something like this:

1. define categories in a dict {key : pattern}
2. define the matching/categorizing function
3. open the input file and begin to iterate entries
4. classify each entry
5. write entry out to the appropriate file

The problem I'm having is with the output files, specifically:

- do I declare them in advance? THe number of categories may change from instance to instance, so I technically don't know how many files to open. Also, there is no guarantee that each category is represented in the input data, hence it would be silly to create files that have no content.

  - if I iterate over the categories in the dict, and open a bunch of files; how do I keep track of which file is for which key? Having another dict i.e. `dict2 {key : file}` feels like overkill and not particularly pretty either...
  - If I don't open the files in advance, and open/close a new io channel every time I need to write to a file, there will be significant overhead I think.

Another complication with opening the files only when needed is the following; every time I run the script I want to overwrite the resultant files. But if I have the file access inside the main loop, I will need to open the file for appending.

Below is the test code I have so far:

```
from itertools import islice
import random, sys, os

cats = {
    "key1" : "<some pattern>",
    "key2" : "<some other pattern>",
    "key3" : "<yet another pattern>"}

def delta(x, s):
    return sum([int(c0 != c1) for c0,c1 in zip(x,s)])

def categorize_str(x, cats):
    d = {cat : delta(x,tag) for cat,tag in cats.items()}
    return min(d, key=d.get)

def main():
    file = sys.argv[1]
    nseq = None if len(sys.argv) < 3 else int(sys.argv[2])

    path = os.path.dirname(file)
    base = os.path.basename(file))
    (name,ext) = os.path.splitext(base)
    for k in cats.keys():  # <----
        outfile = os.path.join(path, ''.join([name, "_", k, ext])
        # what do I do with outfile now???

    read = ... # library call to that opens input file and returns an iterator
    for rec in islice(read,nseq):
        c = categorize_str(rec, cats)
        # depending on c, write to one of the "outfile"s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea: define a class named, say, Pattern.  In here are several member variables: one is the `"<some pattern>"` that you have already; another is the filename; a third is the mode to use for the next call to open() on that file.  The mode would be "w" the first time (creating a new file) and then your code would change that to "w+" so you would append any later writes.  Instances of this class go into the "cats" dictionary as the values.  This addresses your objection to using more than one dictionary - all the information you need to deal with one category is kept in one object. It also allows you to avoid creating empty files.

Perhaps the OS will deal well enough with the problem of doing a lot of small appends to several files.  If that's a performance bottleneck you will have some more work to do (maybe you can cache a few updates in a list before your write them out in one step).